# Distribution of a squared bessel process as its order increases

Tags: statistics

If $B_p(\gamma)$ is a standardized Bessel process of order $p$ (i.e. $B_p(\gamma)=\left\Vert W_p(\gamma)\right\Vert/\sqrt{\gamma}$, with $W_p(\gamma)$ denoting the $p$-dimensional Wiener process), where $\gamma\in[0,1]$ , then what does $\left(B_p^2(\gamma)-p\right)/\sqrt{2p}$ converge to weakly as $p\rightarrow\infty$?

Thanks!